# QGIS 3.4 export DXF creating incorrect polylines

Tags: qgis, dxf, os-mastermap

The layers are exported to `dxf` on `QGIS`. When that is imported back to QGIS or visualise on AutoCAD, incorrect Polylines can be seen.

[image]

Can you please help me to fix this?

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/310379/edit) to add a description as detailed as possible of the steps followed so that your problem can be reproduced. Do not omit to clarify the coordinate reference systems assigned to the layers and the project. If you can, include sample data and screenshots that can be viewed and understood.

Comment: The only difference I can see between those two screenshots, is that the one on the left has black borders on the polygons, and the one on the right has borders that are either light gray or just a darker version of the fill color.